# React-Bootstrap - importing modules

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I'm trying to use react-bootstrap. See the code below. If I load individual modules (eg. Button, ButtonGroup, etc.), it works fine. I'd rather, however, import the whole ReactBootstrap (like in line 2 below) but then, it does not recognise elements like . How do I do it?

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactBootstrap from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { ButtonGroup } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { DropdownButton } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { MenuItem } from 'react-bootstrap';

const NavBar = (props) => {

    return (
        <div>
            <Button bsStyle="success" bsSize="small">
                Something
            </Button>
            <ButtonGroup>
                <DropdownButton bsStyle="success" title="Dropdown">
                    <MenuItem key="1">Dropdown link</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem key="2">Dropdown link</MenuItem>
                </DropdownButton>
                <Button bsStyle="info">Middle</Button>
                <Button bsStyle="info">Right</Button>
            </ButtonGroup>
        </div>
    )

}

export default NavBar;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

react-bootstrap doesn't have a default export, so the default import syntax (`import ReactBootstrap from 'react-bootstrap'`) cannot be used in this case. You can do the following though:

```
import * as ReactBootstrap from 'react-bootstrap';

<ReactBootstrap.Button bsStyle="success" bsSize="small">
  Something
</ReactBootstrap.Button>
```

Comment: so do you need to put `import * as ReactBootstrap from 'react-bootstrap';` in every component? I tried to put it in my `index.js` file in src but it wasn't available in my components then...

Answer (score 19):

The answer provided by Nick **is not** recommended as it will bloat your component.

Rather use the named imports however in a better syntax.

```
import { Button,  ButtonGroup, DropdownButton, MenuItem } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

This way you know what you are importing and keep the component size to a minimum

Comment: I'd prefer to do this, but for some reason, it will not import the children of these components, so I would have to import Navbar.Brand etc